# Laravel MPDF load multiple views

Tags: php, laravel, mpdf

I am using https://github.com/mccarlosen/laravel-mpdf to generate PDF's in my laravel project.

The sample code only allows you to generate a PDF from one file.

```
use PDF;
class ReportController extends Controller {
  public function generate_pdf()
  {
    $data = [
      'foo' => 'bar'
    ];
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.document', $data);
    return $pdf->stream('document.pdf');
  }
}
```

However I need the ability to generate a PDF from 2 separate blade views. This is a simplified example, but I essentially want to create an instance of PDF and then be able to add any number of pages / views to it.

Something like this (does not work):

```
use PDF;
class ReportController extends Controller {
  public function generate_pdf()
  {
    $data = [
      'foo' => 'bar'
    ];

    $pdf = new PDF();

    $pdf->loadView('pdf.document1', $data);
    $pdf->getMpdf()->AddPage();
    $pdf->loadView('pdf.document2', $data);
    
    return $pdf->stream('document.pdf');
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to this problem today and found this unanswered question. I did some digging in the core package and this is how I solved generating a multi-page PDF file using views. Might not be the best way to solve it, but it works. I think the maintainer (or some contributor) of the package would need to add additional code to have it more integrated.

```php
// Define template data
$data = ['foo' => 'bar'];

// Define all views (one view per page)
$pdfPages = [
    'pdf.page1',
    'pdf.page2',
    'pdf.page3'
];

$pdf = null;

// Loop all views
foreach ($pdfPages as $view) {
    // If not yet defined, set the first page
    if (is_null($pdf)) {
        $pdf = PDF::loadView($view, $data);
        continue;
    }

    // Add another page and add HTML from view to this
    $pdf->getMpdf()->AddPage();
    $pdf->getMpdf()->WriteHTML((string)view($view, $data));
}

return $pdf->stream('document.pdf');
```